# RunTimeMethodInfo GetParameters Exception

Tags: .net, exception, reflection, getparameter

I am checking for an assembly through:

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile
```

and I am accessing to a specific type and I'm trying to get the parameters of a specific method.

The problem is that some of the parameters Type is defined in another assembly and this method throws me an exception saying that cannot find the assembly:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'project.POCO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"project.POCO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

How can I set up to this run OK?
Everyone?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have `project.POCO` assembly placed in the same folder that assembly loaded by `Assembly.LoadFile`?

Comment: @KonradKokosa yes is in the same folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/b61s44e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Use the LoadFile method to load and examine assemblies that have the same identity, but are located in different paths. LoadFile does not load files into the LoadFrom context, **and does not resolve dependencies using the load path**, as the LoadFrom method does.

So you should use `Assembly.LoadFrom`, not `Assembly.LoadFile`.